# How to get same named maximum class elements length in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can easily find elements with the same class name length with this code,

```
var classLength = $('.floor-4').length;
```

But how can I get elements with the same class name length dynamically?

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="demo">
  <div class="floor floor-1" data-floor="5" data-floor-sub="0">
    <span class="text">Floor 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-2" data-floor="5" data-floor-sub="1">
    <span class="text">Floor 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-3" data-floor="1" data-floor-sub="2">
    <span class="text">Floor 33</span></div>
  <div class="floor floor-3" data-floor="2" data-floor-sub="2">
    <span class="text">Floor 33</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-3" data-floor="3" data-floor-sub="2">
    <span class="text">Floor 31</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-3" data-floor="4" data-floor-sub="2">
    <span class="text">Floor 31</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-3" data-floor="5" data-floor-sub="2">
    <span class="text">Floor 32</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-3" data-floor="6" data-floor-sub="2">
    <span class="text">Floor 33</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-3" data-floor="7" data-floor-sub="2">
    <span class="text">Floor 33</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-3" data-floor="8" data-floor-sub="2">
    <span class="text">Floor 33</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-3" data-floor="9" data-floor-sub="2">
    <span class="text">Floor 33</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-4" data-floor="0" data-floor-sub="3">
    <span class="text">Floor 4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-4" data-floor="1" data-floor-sub="3">
    <span class="text">Floor 4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-4" data-floor="2" data-floor-sub="3">
    <span class="text">Floor 4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-4" data-floor="3" data-floor-sub="3">
    <span class="text">Floor 4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-4" data-floor="4" data-floor-sub="3">
    <span class="text">Floor 4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-4" data-floor="5" data-floor-sub="3">
    <span class="text">Floor 4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-4" data-floor="6" data-floor-sub="3">
    <span class="text">Floor 4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-4" data-floor="7" data-floor-sub="3">
    <span class="text">Floor 4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-4" data-floor="8" data-floor-sub="3">
    <span class="text">Floor 4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-4" data-floor="9" data-floor-sub="3">
    <span class="text">Floor 4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-4" data-floor="10" data-floor-sub="3">
    <span class="text">Floor 4</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-5" data-floor="4" data-floor-sub="4">
    <span class="text">Floor 5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-5" data-floor="5" data-floor-sub="4">
    <span class="text">Floor 5</span>
  </div>
  <div class="floor floor-5" data-floor="6" data-floor-sub="4">
    <span class="text">Floor 5</span>
  </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean dynamically?

Comment: Wrapped it in a function and call it when you need.

Comment: @BhavO. How can i find maximum length of class name?

Comment: Maximum length of the class name string, or you need to largest number that is on end of floor- ?

Comment: Maximum length of the class name. @BhavO

Comment: So you want to find all .floor elements and find the length of the longest classname, at the moment they all have same length

Comment: @BhavO, No. I want to find highest length of the same named class selectors. Here,  .floor-1 length = 1, .floor-2 length = 1, .floor-3 length = 9, .floor-4 length = 11 and .floor-5 length = 3. But, how can i find .floor-4 class with jquery. In future .floor-3 length will be 13 that time i want get .floor3 class.

Comment: hi @Sathya see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this, this will return the class name of the most occuring, or the first class if they are the same (if you have two classes with same max):

```
function getMaxFloorClass(){
    var groups = {}, max = 0, maxClass;
    $(".floor").each(function(i, item){
        var classname = $(item).attr('class');
        groups[classname] = groups[classname] || 0;
        groups[classname]++;
    });

    for(group in groups){
        if(groups[group] > max){
            maxClass = group;
            max = groups[group];
        }
    }
    return maxClass;
}
```

working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/kvycjh19/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can abstract it using a function that returns the number of elements with that class, either from the class name or the class selector (preceding dot):

```
var classCount = function(classString){
    return document.getElementsByClassName(class).length;
};

var countClass = function(classSelector){
    return document.querySelectorAll(classSelector).length;
};
```

And if you wish for a custom jQuery method:

```
jQuery.fn.classCount = function(classString){
    return $(classString).length;
};
```